# Step-by-Step selecting and moving vertices to absolute positions

Tags: modeling

I'm not sure why this is so hard in blender or perhaps not (I just don't know how to do it).  Please look at the below model:

[image]

I want to accomplish 2 things.

1) Drag select all topmost vertices (there are 4 as one is behind another one).

2) Move all of the Z locations to an exact world coordinate (0.2)

Now please tell me in the least amount of steps how this can be done in blender.  In max I can just drag/select all vertices.  I can then update all of their Z values in 1 input box to drop them all down in one operation.

I know that blender is different but I'm used to modeling building block pieces like this and require this kind of functionality all the time.

If there is not an easy way to do this then please tell me how you all model to get accurate building blocks.

Thanks,
- Jeff

Comment: Hit N button in 3d view window, that will open a panel where you will be able to update transform values.

Comment: OK.  I'll try that.  Any idea on how to easily mass select vertices sharing the same plane regardless of if it is behind another one or back facing?

Comment: B shortcut to box select in wireframe mode

Comment: or C brush select in wireframe mode, press g and z to transform the selected vertices along the z-axis

Answer (score 4):

- In the 3D view, press <kbd>N</kbd> once or twice to open the
  right-hand sidebar.
- Find the '3D Cursor' Section and set the Z value to your desired
  value, 0.2 in this case.
- At the bottom of the 3D view, set the Pivot Center to '3D Cursor'.
- Drag select your vertices with <kbd>B</kbd>.
- Hit <kbd>S</kbd> (for scale), then <kbd>Z</kbd> (to limit scaling
  along the z-axis), then <kbd>0</kbd> (zero).

Comment: The B for box select is exactly what I was looking for.  However the other idea to simply use the N button to set the absolute positioning without any 3d cursor was much faster and simpler.

Comment: I agree. In this particular case, making a direct change to the vertex coordinates is faster. Consider, however, other cases, which are much more likely to occur: You need to align one or more vertices to another vertex. Sure, you can read that one vertex's coordinates and manually apply them to the other vertex, or you can set the 3D cursor to that vertex (Shift + <kbd>S</kbd>, select the other vertices, and scale to zero along the appropriate axis. This workflow will serve you well for a broader range of circumstances than the narrow scope of your question. Food for thought...

Comment: Blender rookie here. In Blender 2.82, is it not enough to select the vertices, and set the value in the right sidebar > Item > Transform > Z?